# XSLT Get All Nodes where parent node is not type

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have a structure similar to as follows:

```
<list>
   <newsItem title="Item1"></newsItem>
   <newsItem title="Item2"></newsItem>
   <newsItem title="Item3"></newsItem>
   <newsItem title="Item4"></newsItem>
   <newsItemCategory title="Cat1">
          <newsItem title="Item1"></newsItem>
          <newsItem title="Item2"></newsItem>
          <newsItem title="Item3"></newsItem>
          <newsItem title="Item4"></newsItem>
   </newsItemCategory>
   <newsItem title="Item5"></newsItem>
   <newsItem title="Item6"></newsItem>
</list>
```

I am doing a for-each loop and I want all nodes of type newsItem or newsItemCateogory but I don't want to bring back newsItems that are within a newsItemCategory.

to get everything my XSLT is doing the following:

```
$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::root//* [name() = "newsItem" or name() = "newsItemCategory"]
```

I am trying to filter this:

```
  $currentPage/ancestor-or-self::root//* [parent::node/name() != "newsItemCategory" and (name() = "newsItem" or name() = "newsItemCategory")]
```

I don't know if this is the right syntax or if it's possible, but it is not bringing back the results I am looking for.

Comment: Can you show  how the `$currentPage` variable is defined? Thanks!

Comment: @Tim C This is an Umbraco XSLT and $currentPage is passed in as a parameter. I should have made that clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `parent::` and `self::` axes without having to resort to `name()` checks.

```
$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[last()]//*[
    self::newsItem or self::newsItemCategory
]
```

and I recommend using `not()` over `!=`:

```
$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[last()]//*[
    (self:newsItem or self::newsItemCategory) and not(parent::newsItemCategory)
]
```

I'm using `ancestor-or-self::*[last()]` to get to the top-most element in a generic way, because `ancestor-or-self::root` potentially selects more than one element. I don't know how Umbraco templates look like and if this really can happen or not.